# Android: Waiting dialog for user close

Tags: android, dialog

```
private boolean popup(String title, String message, int resID) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(PRO.this);
    dialog.setContentView(resID == 0 ? R.layout.dialog : resID);
    dialog.setTitle(title);

    final Object[]  result = {false};
    Button butonOk = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok);
    Button butonCancel = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cancel);
    TextView text = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
    text.setText(message);
    butonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result[0] = true;
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    butonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

    if((Boolean)result[0]){
        PRO.log("OK");
    }else{
        PRO.log("FALSE");
    }
    return (Boolean)result[0];
}
```

When  I run my app I show my dialog normally, but when opening dialog o see directly **"FALSE"** so **I want to when user input then I show the message.**
So maybe `dialog.show()` then block the Thread?

Answer (score 1):

you have to put your comment/action inside OnClick method like

```
butonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

      if((Boolean)result[0]){
          PRO.log("OK");
      }else{
          PRO.log("FALSE");
      }
      dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for reply but top bottom in method have return (Boolean)result[0]; (so now im edit my subject sorry and ty)

Comment: then you have to call other method on clicking of dialogue in any button and return value from that method